# boost program_options custom validation

Tags: c++, validation, boost

i am trying to understand program_options custom validation in order to transform python code into c++ one.
any way
i read in the example that i have to overload validate function
i m trying to find the original function in boost program_options files but in vain
can any body just tell me where is the original validate function which i ll over load it
it is silly question but i wanna know how it validate on default to get idea about the concept of validation and how it is done
thanks in advance

Comment: The way I did this was by creating a new type for each option. Then overloading `operator <<` and `>>` for it. I perform validation in the `operator <<`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on my one-line comment, I have always found boost::program_options to be a little deficient in argument validation.

As a result I have found that it's often easier to write a custom class for each option type. Normally program_options uses `operator>>` to decode the option value, so if you override this you get a chance to throw an exception that program_options recognises. If you use nested exceptions, you can print quite detailed error diagnostics.

Example:

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

namespace po = boost::program_options;

// a custom option type
struct foo_or_bar {
    std::string value;

    // self-describing
    static constexpr const char *option_name() { return "foo"; }

    static constexpr const char *description() { return "single option only. value must be either foo or bar"; }

    // check the value and throw a nested exception chain if it's wrong    
    void check_value() const
    try {
        if (value != "foo" and value != "bar") {
            std::ostringstream ss;
            ss << "value must be foo or bar, you supplied " << std::quoted(value);
            throw std::invalid_argument(ss.str());
        }
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::throw_with_nested(po::validation_error(po::validation_error::invalid_option_value, option_name()));

    }

    // overload operators
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, foo_or_bar &arg) {
        is >> arg.value;
        arg.check_value();
        return is;
    }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, foo_or_bar const &arg) {
        return os << arg.value;
    }

};

// test
void test(int argc, const char **argv) {
    foo_or_bar my_foo;

    po::options_description desc("test options");
    desc.add_options()
            (foo_or_bar::option_name(), po::value(&my_foo), foo_or_bar::description());

    po::variables_map vm;
    po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);
    po::notify(vm);


    std::cout << "foo is " << my_foo << std::endl;
}

void print_exception(const std::exception& e, int level =  0)
{
    std::cerr << std::string(level, ' ') << "exception: " << e.what() << '\n';
    try {
        std::rethrow_if_nested(e);
    } catch(const std::exception& e) {
        print_exception(e, level+1);
    } catch(...) {}
}

int main() {
    {
        std::vector<const char *> test_args = {
                "executable_name",
                "--foo=bar"
        };
        test(test_args.size(), test_args.data());
    }

    try {
        std::vector<const char *> test_args = {
                "executable_name",
                "--foo=bob"
        };
        test(test_args.size(), test_args.data());
    }
    catch (std::exception const &e) {
        print_exception(e);
    }
}
```

expected output:

```
foo is bar
exception: the argument for option '--foo' is invalid
 exception: value must be foo or bar, you supplied "bob"
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply ..i m still beginner so that i find the expression "static constexpr const char * " alittle complicated.. i think it will be method of type  pointer to static "staying alive during running" constexpr"i dont understand it because it is really followed by const char" ....but your appraoch in concept is great ....i was looking for the position of validate function and i think i found a template for it in some forums....thanks again for your reply